# How to bind an element to a selected menuitem wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, menuitem

I'm adding items to a menuitem through the itemsSource property. (element name is videoCapDevices)

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Devices}}"
```

And now i want to respond to the selected menuitem , may be to show a videostream with the selected camera devices

```
VideoCaptureDevice="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=videoCapDevices}"
```

But this just works for comboboxes or listboxes.

How can i change the "path selector" to reach the selected menuitem.

Thank you

Comment: Devices is just a static source ... for example             ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Controls:MultimediaUtil.VideoInputDevices}}"

Comment: And how are the VideoInputDevices holding up, playing for MenuItem?

Comment: I would look at SelectedItem in the debugger to find out what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

try to cast using a **converter**

```
public class DeviceConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       if(value==null)
          return null;

        return ((Device)value).CaptureDeviceName;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

and

```
 VideoCaptureDevice="{Binding Converter=DeviceConverter ,Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=videoCapDevices}"
```

Comment: now the compiler throws an exception, that it cannot convert the type (string ) into the IValueConverter type... thing is that in the original example from [WPFMediaKit](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/) worked... exact the same way like above just with a combobox instead of a menuitem... I think the problem is the path selection to a menuitem.

Comment: i updated my converter making `CaptureDeviceName` property as the output @onkelFungus

Comment: i did not find this property where do you find it ? 
Do you meant `DsDevice.Name` ? I tried with a return value `DsDevice` but compiler throws same exception again... could you show me the way you mean it? @seddik-laraba

Comment: `XamlParseException` , but in the InnerException stands an `InvalidCastException` (Type String cannot be converted into type IValueConverter) , so i think he gets a string object from the binding but i dont understand why he cant convert it...